# How do I write a function in PHP that takes an array and returns an array if any two values in the input array equal a targeted sum

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
function twoNumberSum($array,$targetSum) {
   sort($array);
   $left = 0;
   $right = count($array) - 1;
   while ($left < $right) {
       $currentSum = $array[$left] + $array[$right];
       if($currentSum == $targetSum) {
            print_r([$array[$left], $array[$right]]);
       } else if ($currentSum < $targetSum) {
           $left += 1;
       } else if ($currentSum > $targetSum) {
           $right -= 1;
       }
   }
   return [];
}
```

```
    $numArray = [3,5,-4,8,11,1,-1,6];
    $targetSum = 10;
    twoNumberSum($numArray,$targetSum);
```

**The Goal**

My goal here is to use pointers to slowly work through the array on both ends, all the while adding the values at array[left] and array[right]. If the currentSum is less than the targetSum, the left pointer moves up by one. If the currentSum is greater than the targetSum, the right pointer goes down by one. If currentSum and targetSum are equal, the function returns an array of array[left] and array[right].

**The Problem**

For some reason, when I run the code with the above array and target value, with the expected output being (11, -1), I get the expected output, but it's repeated several times over. I actually wouldn't encourage you all to run this code on your machines. I'll include a screenshot of what I'm seeing. [output from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdWbU.png)

**What I've tried**

I've tried exiting the function using the return keyword beneath where I'm calling the print_r function. And this works, but only to a certain degree. In the event that targetValue is equal to 4, in which case the expected output is (3,1) (5,-1), and (-4,8), the output only returns the last valid pair of integers rather than all of them.

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think the problem here is, if you find a sum that equals target sum, you don't increment either left or right, and keep looping over that same sum, right?

Comment: also, i can imagine a scenario, where once this is fixed, you increment the wrong side, and miss a matching sum. imagine the array `[0,0,1,10]` and a target of 10, and on a target sum match you choose to decrement the right. or vice versa with the array `[0,1,10,10]' and you choose to increment the left on a target sum match. but if you are returning a value, instead of trying to find all matches, i suppose that fixes both problems.

Comment: @dqhendricks These are really great points. Thanks. I'm going to try and work through the code again with these considerations

Answer (score 0):

cycle through the array, and for each element, cycle through the rest of the array to test sums.

```
function twoNumberSum ( $inputArray, $targetSum ) {
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $inputArray ) - 1; $i++ ) {
        for ( $e = $i + 1; $e < count( $inputArray ); $e++ ) {
            if ( $inputArray[$i] + $inputArray[$e] == $targetSum ) return [];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$numArray = [3,5,-4,8,11,1,-1,6];
$targetSum = 10;
var_dump( twoNumberSum( $numArray, $targetSum ) );
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but I'm specifically looking to do it using the method in the OP because, in theory, it's faster. Whereas you're cycling through the array N times for each element in the array, the method I'm using just goes through the array once. Thank you though for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @smcgregor1 i don't loop N times, as the second loops starts at `i+1` doing each comparison only once. but i see how sorting could still manage to do it in less.

Answer (score 0):

To compare all elements of the array with each other, 2 loops are necessary. This solution uses 2 forech loops and returns all possible pairs that satisfy the condition. There is no need to manually create a copy of $inputArray as PHP forech works internally with copies.

```
function twoNumberSum ( $inputArray, $targetSum ) {
    $res = [];
    foreach($inputArray as $i => $firstVal){
        array_shift($inputArray);
        foreach($inputArray as $secVal){
            if ( $firstVal + $secVal == $targetSum ) {
              $res[] = [$firstVal,$secVal] ;
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$numArray = [3,5,-4,8,11,1,-1,6];
$targetSum = 4;

var_export( twoNumberSum( $numArray, $targetSum ) );
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 5,
    1 => -1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => -4,
    1 => 8,
  ),
)
```

[Try self.](https://3v4l.org/lMJTt)